# Aperture: use iptc tags for face recognition

Tags: aperture

I have about 10'000 pictures with iptc tags. Aperture shows this tags after the pictures have been imported.

Most of the tags are person names. Is there a way to use this tags to assist face regocnition of aperture? I can make an intelligent album, but I did not find a way to tell aperture to treat all person on this pictures as the one I know is on the picture.